# Android - Possible to implement simple firewall enforcement?

Tags: android, network-programming

This is going to sound strange, and please don't judge the impracticality of doing something like this, but I need to add support for controlling out bound network traffic from an Android device. Doesn't have to be selective. I basically need to put the device in a mode where out bound communication is silenced over WIFI. (primarily) The reason for this is I have a networked application that's remotely controlled and I need to be able to put it to "communication sleep" on-demand and then "wake it up" after a period of time, or on-demand. The on-demand aspect is controlled remotely. Hence the need to put the device in a state where it'll only accept in bound communication.

I'm primarily interested in TCP/UDP blocking of out bound traffic. I'm not interested in a separate firewall app. My application includes a service that's already implementing all the communication code required. I just need some suggestions on how to control out bound communication.

FYI, I have a mix of 2.3 and 4.0 devices to work with.

Could I have my service implement some basic firewall support? Maybe a simple proxy that the device is configured to use? (similar to the Ad Block app)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. If it's at all possible, I'll try to share the code for it here.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I have and require root on these devices anyways.

On the proxy idea, really I just need a black hole listening on a port. If I can set the system proxy settings from my app, when the out bound communication needs to be disabled, I can enable the proxy and drop all connections.

If I can't set the system proxy settings, I'll have to implement a working proxy, require the user configure the proxy, and control it's behavior accordingly when connections are received.

Comment: I'd guess not unless you have root.

Comment: Cripes, my GingerBread 2.3.4 Lenovo A1s don't have the proxy setting under WIFI advanced! ARG... I can't do the proxy approach since the system can't be configured to use one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might as well answer my own question. With root you can include iptables and make some command line calls to control the traffic flow. Note that you should have some experience with stateful firewall concepts, as mucking with outbound DENYs will lead you to confusion unless you know exactly what the system/app is supposed to do. (random response ports, etc...)

A proxy service would work for Android devices and versions which allow for network proxy support. Unfortunately not all my devices allow for it. (my Ginger Bread devices don't have proxy support, it's just not present in the UI, and the API is read only for the HTTP_PROXY System setting)

So there's no example code to offer. I'm playing with iptables on my devices. I'll likely include it in my application, which requires root anyways.